# Specific Partition D: full storage for SharePoint Data

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2013

I've run into a problem where my partition DATA(D:) run out of space for SharePoint Data. When i tried to extend the partition D: the Extend Volume context menu was unable to click or greyed out.
My question is how or is it okay to change the Content Database Server Properties on Database Setting for that particular database default locations. Image here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRHYX.jpg)

or this will affect the entire SharePoint data when i change that locations?
It is okay to just have another partition for example DATA2(F:), copy the folders in the Data(D:) and paste to DATA2(F:) ?

Need help on this .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it, It just need to disconnect connection in for the partition D: and boot up server and manage using partition tool and added some extra storage.